# Display an "offline" message when a external page is offline (PHP)

Tags: php

I have an number of ads displaying on my website that reads the balance of a Blockchain.info bitcoin address but their system for keeping the address balances online keeps going down.

What I want is to do is display a message when the address (not the website) can't be read.

The balance is always between 0 and 10 (and can be a decimal within that range).

I will save you reading all the curl code and just post what I have at the end of my PHP:

```
if ($BitcoinAddressBalance >= -0 && $BitcoinAddressBalance < 10) {
echo 'Online';
} else {
echo 'Offline';
}
```

My problem is that the code echoes 'Online' even when there is no data/numbers or I use a unregistered domain.

Can I use curl to check a page on a website has a number between 0 and 10?

Comment: Can you show what is in the `$BitcoinAddressBalance`?

Comment: curl_exec() should return FALSE if the server is offline. You can compare the return value with === . If you use == then you cannot differentiate a successful return with zero balance and a failed request.

Comment: Thanks msound, I will use that if Majidarif's solution has problems. At the moment there seems to be a dozen different curl functions and I am getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether if the value in `$BitcoinAddressBalance` is not empty then you can use the following:

```
if ( isset($BitcoinAddressBalance) ) {
   echo 'Online';
} else {
   echo 'Offline';
}
```

Comment: Hi Majidarif. That seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for that.